# Open a wpf Page using Path/URI

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to do something like this:

```
var iFrame = new Frame();
var iPage = new Page(new Uri("/Views/MyPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
//                              ^ this must be the parameter on creating the page

iFrame.Content = iView;
tabCtrl.Content = iFrame;
```

Wherein, I want to open the page using the path instead of instantiating the page itself which is functionally correct like this:

```
var iFrame = new Frame();
var iPage = new MyPage();

iFrame.Content = iView;
tabCtrl.Content = iFrame;
```

My idea is to use a maintained path for the Page stored in the database.
Any thoughts?

Comment: How about using an user control instead for a page? so that you can add it's object directly to the tabbed control,

Comment: Please elaborate? I need to have the path as the parameter.

Comment: see if the following answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221571/modern-ui-wpf-navigation/24228627#24228627

Comment: Thank you @pushpraj, but I am looking for something like how I can instantiate the existing page using that URI then add it as content/

Comment: are you getting an error of any sort? it looks like you may need to escape your "/"'s  i.e. `@"/Views/MyPage.xaml" ` or `"//Views//MyPage.xaml",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    System.Uri resource =  new System.Uri(@"Views\MyPage.xaml", System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    Something.Content = System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(resource);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `myUserControl.xaml` be the user control, then you can add this user control to the tabbed item as like the following;

```
myUserControl myUserControlObject= new myUserControl();
tabCtrl.Content=myUserControlObject;
```

and you have to import the `myUserControl` class like: `using project.Views` since it belongs to view namespace. check whether a page can be added like this or not

Comment: Yes, but I need to create this myUserControl using the Path like in my example.